# Java hashmap choose random but by chance

Tags: java, random, hashmap, maps

I have 2 hashmaps.

```
rewards<integer,integer>
chances<integer,integer>
```

rewards is like : `57,500000000;9210,2500;9209,50;6660,1;6`  (id-count)

chances is like : `57,95;9210,70;9209,65;6660,15;`  (id-chance %) id is the same both maps.

So i want to choose one id but by these chances so low chances will have lower chance to be selected. i am fully confused. thanks you! (but i need to chooce 1 id , not zero not more than 1)

Comment: _"i am fully confused"_: me too

Comment: can you possibly reword you question?

Comment: i just want to select an id from rewards , but with chances not all to be the same chance.. for example 57 id has chance 95% , 9210 id has chance 70%

Comment: you want to specify the probability for each entry?

Comment: yes the chance for each id

Comment: as far as I know there is Integer not integer in java

Comment: Sum the total chance percentages, generate a random number lower than it, then map that number back to an index.

Answer (score 0):

[This explains it in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435183/generate-a-weighted-random-number).

```
int sumOfPercentages = ...; //ex) 100
Random ran = new Random();
int ranNumber = ran.nextInt(sumOfPercentages);

Integer id = -1;
int current = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : chances.entrySet())
{
    current += entry.getValue();
    if(ranNumber < current)
    {
      id = entry.getKey();
      break;
    }
}

System.out.println(rewards.get(id));
```