# Generate random number in interval with given probability

Tags: java

I want to generate a random number with a given probability but I'm not sure how to:

I have a two dimensional array:  int[ ][ ] aryNumbers = new int[4][]

and for each number(4) I want to generate a int result in a inteval of [1...9] with a prob of 0.5 .Otherwise a number in a interval of [10...99].

Note: I know how to generate a number, but choosing between intervals confused me.

**Edit:**

```
 public int numberAttribution(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    double dbNum = rand.nextDouble();
    int intNum;
    int min1 = 1, max1 = 9, range1 = max1 - min1 + 1;
    int min2 = 10, max2 = 99, range2 =  max2 - min2 + 1;

    if(dbNum < 0.5){
        intNum = rand.nextInt(range1) + min1;
    }else{
        intNum = rand.nextInt(range2) + min2;
    } 
       System.out.print(intNum);
    return intNum;
}
```

Comment: Generate a random number between 0 and 1; if its value is less than 0.5, scale it to the range [1..9]; otherwise, scale it to the range [10..99].

Comment: you just need `Random#nextDouble` without parameter (creats a value between 0.0-1.0) an if statement and `Random#nextInt`

Comment: you can do `r.nextBoolean() ? r.nextInt(9) + 1 : r.nextInt(90) + 10`

Comment: This is what I have done:                                                                      public int numberAttribution(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        double dbNum = rand.nextDouble();
        int intNum;
        int min1 = 1, max1 = 9, range1 = max1 - min1 + 1;
        int min2 = 10, max2 = 99, range2 =  max2 - min2 + 1;
        
        if(dbNum < 0.5){
            intNum = rand.nextInt(range1) + min1;
        }else{
            intNum = rand.nextInt(range2) + min2;
        } 
           System.out.print(intNum);
    return intNum;
    }

Comment: @CyberAllien You don't need all that - the expression I posted above generates what you want

Comment: The more generic version of your problem is generating a weighed random number. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435183/generate-a-weighted-random-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I got you right, you want a 50% chance to generate a number between 1 and 9, otherwise generate a number between 10 and 99?

In that case you could do it like this:

```
int randomNumber = 0;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    randomNumber = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 9);
} else {
    randomNumber = 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 90);
}
```

[Runnable version](http://ideone.com/Ho1QzD)

Comment: Why (Math.random() > 0.5). They told me before to do some think less then 0.5 to inter in [1...9] interval

Comment: This will result in a number in [0..8] half the time and [0...98] the rest.

Comment: @jsheeran: woops, fixed in a minute #Edit: Fixed

Comment: This will result in a number in [0..8] half the time and [0...98] the rest.       So if I want a number  in [1..9] (inclued)half the time and [1...99] (included) the rest

Comment: @CyberAllien: That's what jsheeran already mentioned, I already fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this method will be called millions of times a second. In that case it might be wise to only generate one random each time:

```
  private static int generateRandom() {
    double rand = Math.random();
    if (rand < 0.5) {
      rand *= 18;
      rand += 1;
    } else {
      rand -= 0.5;
      rand *= 180;
      rand += 10;
    }
    return (int) rand;
  }
```