# Return value based on probability and percentage

Tags: javascript, probability

Any idea how I could implement probability in regards to these examples.

```
let directions = [
    {
        1: {
            left: {
                successRate: 1,
                direction: 0
            },
            top: {
                successRate: 35,
                direction: 1
            },
            right: {
                successRate: 15,
                direction: 2
            },
            bottom: {
                successRate: 5,
                direction: 3
            }
        },
    }
]
```

1. Should loop through the properties.
2. Loop through top,right,bottom, left to retrieve their successRate value
3. Randomly retrieve a direction based on it's successRate (aka it's probability) in comparison to everything. The ones with the higher probability should have a higher chance of being called.

The program is within a setInterval and everytime the interval loops, it is suppose to print the values. I tried many different ways but I can't figure it out.

UPDATE For the actual problem that I am currently having.

You can ignore the "Not Found". It's just a random string. The numbers generate randomly according to the probability but after x amount of calls within a setInterval function, it becomes "undefined".

CODE:

```
let directions = [
    {
        1: {
            left: {
                successRate: 5,
                direction: 0
            },
            top: {
                successRate: 3,
                direction: 1
            },
            right: {
                successRate: 10,
                direction: 2
            },
            bottom: {
                successRate: 30,
                direction: 3
            }
        },
    }
]

var chances = [40, 30, 15, 10, 5]; 
let items = Object.values(directions[0][1]);

function chooseWeighted(items, chances) {
    var sum = chances.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el, 0);
    var acc = 0;
    chances = chances.map(el => (acc = el + acc));
    var rand = Math.random() * sum;
    return items[chances.filter(el => el <= rand).length];
}

function scanPlayerArea(){
    console.log(chooseWeighted(items, chances).direction);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Not found.
1
Not found.
0
Not found.
0
Not found.
2
Not found.
0
Not found.
1
Not found.
1
Not found.
0
Not found.
0
Not found.
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Script\file.js:1351
    dir = chooseWeighted(items, chances).direction;
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'direction' of undefined
    at scanPlayerArea (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Script\file.js:1351:41)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Script\file.js:1633:6)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)

C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Script>
```

THE LOOP:

```
setInterval(function(){
    scanPlayerArea()
}, 50);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose a weighted random array element in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566019/how-to-choose-a-weighted-random-array-element-in-javascript)

Comment: No because I tried that already. It doesn't match up with the type of data I am using. It's a simple array and mine is a layered array object.

Comment: `Object.values(directions[0]["1"])` and you have an array, stripping off two layers of indirection (a single element array and a single entry object) that feel unneeded in the first place. You can easily adapt the algorithm shown to work with an object anyway--build an array with the desired probabilities, then randomly choose an element from this weighted array. Then index into your object with the key and you're done. Now, if performance matters you need a more advanced algo, and the solutions in related threads can help.

Comment: You are right but I realized the problem is different. I am placing the randomizer inside a setInterval function and after a few calls of returning the correct value, it becomes "undefined"? any ideas

Comment: If that's the problem, please show the [mcve] so someone can help. I (usually) can't debug code I can't see.

Comment: _"I tried many different ways but I can't figure it out."_ Please show us at least one of those ways.

Comment: @kmoser All done. I updated the code.

Comment: If the probability of picking a direction has to do with its `successRate`, what is the purpose of the `chances` array?

Comment: If you already solved it you should either make an accepted response to your own question or remove the question. Either way it wasn't clear for me neither what's the difference between successRate and chances

Comment: The values filled in chances is suppose to actually be the values from the object with the keys of successRate but either way the program still crashes @alotropico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to pickup a random direction on each iteration based on the probability set on the successRate property. If so, here is a way I can think of doing it:

```js
let directions = [
    {
        1: {
            left: {
                successRate: 5,
                direction: 0
            },
            top: {
                successRate: 3,
                direction: 1
            },
            right: {
                successRate: 10,
                direction: 2
            },
            bottom: {
                successRate: 30,
                direction: 3
            }
        },
    }
];

const items = directions[0][1];

// Calculate the total rate 100%, just a sum of all the items
let totalRate = 0;
for (var key of Object.keys(items)) {
    totalRate += items[key].successRate;
}

// Calculate the coeficient of success rate for each item and save it in items
let lastCoef = 0;
for (var key of Object.keys(items)) {
  items[key].coef = lastCoef + items[key].successRate / totalRate;
  lastCoef = items[key].coef;
  console.log(key + ' coeficient: ' + lastCoef);
}

function chooseWeighted(items) {
  const randomNum = Math.random();
  for (var key of Object.keys(items)) {
    if(randomNum < items[key].coef) {
      return key;
    }
  }
}

function scanPlayerArea(){
  console.log(chooseWeighted(items));
}

setInterval(function(){
  scanPlayerArea();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Much appreciated!