# Return a Record Based on Weight Field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a 2 collections.  One is for Locations and another for configurations.  Each location can have many locations.  When I query a location I want to return a configuration based on the weight assigned to that configuration.  As an example:

location A has 3 configurations

- Config1.weight = 500
- Config2.weight = 1000
- Config3.weight = 1000

The weights above mean that Config1 has a 20% chance of being returned and Config2/3 have a 40% chance each.  I get this percentage by adding the weights and then dividing by the individual weight which gives the percentage.

Config1 example:

- 500 + 1000 + 1000 = 2500
- 500 / 2500 = .2
- .2 * 100 = 20% chance

I am struggling to find a relatively easy way of doing this in an aggregate.

As a side note:  This is a new system so I am able to change how the weights are stored/used if there is a better method.

Comment: Could you review the question pretending you know nothing about the context? It's how we read it and "Each location can have many locations" doesn't make much sense without further explanations. Neither does "return a configuration based on the weight". "based" is quite vague definition. With your example of 3 configurations, what weight do you query and what you expect in the result?

Comment: I ended up doing this in my micro-service via Javascript rather than at the database level, although I would still like to pursue an option in the database to avoid returning unnecessary results for further processing.  To answer your questions:  A location is a physical location in the US and a configuration is shown to a user, it's mostly HTML.  We run a lot of experiments so each configuration is a different GUI/Experiment that we run.  What I expect to return is a single configuration rather than an array, based on the weight.  Config 1 should be returned 20% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the solution discussed here, although it was not in MongoDB, but rather my nodejs micro-service used to return the configuration files.

[How to choose a weighted random array element in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566019/how-to-choose-a-weighted-random-array-element-in-javascript/55671924)