# I want to set up a randomizer for a list/array in Javascript according to weighted probability

Tags: javascript, react-native

Essentially I will have a list of N elements. I want to set up a list randomizer where each element in the list has a probability of appearing first or at the top of the list.

For example, if I have 5 elements in a list, I to setup a randomizer where one element has a 25% chance of appearing first and the other elements have an equal probability(18.75%) of appearing first in the list

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I read another stackoverflow thread about randomizers with weighted proabailities but those involve selecting an item and not randomizing the entire list. I am a very new self learning developer so the main things that I tried were basic randomizers such as the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69335458/weighted-probability-random-choice-array