# Random selection function for weighted array elements

Tags: javascript, math, statistics, probability

In the initial state we've got a list of elements having different weights from zero to one.

```
let list = [
  0.1,
  0.83,
  0.65,
  0.9,
  0.23,
  0.17,
  0.87,
  0.34
];
```

In the final state we will need to pick **only one** element, **though** the probability should influence the result by its weight.

**Question:**
*How should the selection function look like, to solve that mathematical problem?*

Comment: I can't even articulate how that mathematical problem is called. If you can help me to find the correct nomenclature, it will be a huge aid!

Comment: @barmar im reopening cause the dupe answers are not satisfying IMO

Comment: @JonasW. There should be other questions that do satisfy. This is a common question.

Comment: How about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435183/generate-a-weighted-random-number

Comment: @barmar yes thats better. Found that a second ago ;)

Comment: You could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2718/

Comment: @NenadVracar Thank you for you post, please add it as an answer. I love your one-liner. I've published it also here: https://beta.observablehq.com/@nextlevelshit/rejection-sampling-in-javascript

Comment: @NEXTLEVELSHIT The question is closed now.

Comment: Can't understand it, because you gave a new way to fix that problem. Sorry!

Comment: @NenadVracar You could add it as an answer to the linked question.