# Random number with percentage

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random, percentage

I have this:

```
var users = [user1, user2, user3];
var chances = [20, 20, 60];
var total = 100;
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * total) + 1);

if (random > 40 && random < 100) {
    console.log('winner:', users[2]);
}

if (random > 20 && random < 40) {
    console.log('winner:', users[1]);
}

if (random > 0 && random < 20) {
    console.log('winner:', users[0]);
}
```

This will give every user a fair chance to win. (60 has a 60% chance, 20 has a 20% chance).

But what I actually need is that this is a dynamic for each (or anything else) function.

Example of my thoughts:

```
 chances.forEach(function(entry) {
     if (unknownValue > unkownValue2 && unknownValue3 < unknownValue4) {
         console.log('winner:', unknownUser);
     };
 });
```

So basically, if the value for the chances array are 50, 100 and 20 the chance that number 100 wins must be 2x higher than 50, and 5x higher than 20.

Im happy for every answer and please do not mark this as duplicate for slot machines percentages, this is NOT what i need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate A Weighted Random Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435183/generate-a-weighted-random-number)

Comment: Also you do not allow for 20 or 40 in your ifs above

Comment: You do realise that weight _is_ percentages, don't you?

Comment: Why do you set the total to 50? That will reduce the chance for user3. It should be 100, no?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an alternative to the probability solutions, you could also create an array with duplicate users so that their count corresponds to the associated percentage. It is then required that your percentages are positive integers, not fractions.

Like this:

```js
const users = [
  {name: "Jim",   pct: 20},
  {name: "Helen", pct: 20},
  {name: "Anna",  pct: 60}
];

const expanded = users.flatMap(user => Array(user.pct).fill(user));
const winner = expanded[Math.floor(Math.random() * expanded.length)];
console.log("winner: " + winner.name);
```

The numbers don't really have to be percentages. If you need more precision, just use bigger numbers that maybe add up to 1000 or 10000.

Comment: Hey, really awesome answer! Just to clarify, the numbers sum of the pct's doesnt need to be 1, 100, or 1000? I mean, 12,43,89 would also work right?

Comment: Yep, the total is used (with `expanded.length`) and so the random number that is generated will be picked up to that limit, whatever it may be. The only limitation is that they should not have fractions and should not be astronomically big, since this solution temporarily allocates memory proportionate to those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Transform ratios into percentages. Apparently, their sum should account for 1, and value for each is `val/total`:

```js
function transformRatiosToAccPercentages(ratios) {
  const total = ratios.reduce((sum, el) => sum += el, 0);
  let acc = 0;
  const accPercentages = ratios.map(rat => acc += rat / total);
  return accPercentages;
}

function chooseBiasedRandom(accPercentages) {
  const random = Math.random();
  const index = accPercentages.findIndex(acc => random < acc);
  return index;
}

// And that's how it can be used:

const users = {
  Alpha: 50,
  Bravo: 100,
  Charlie: 10
};

const userNames = Object.keys(users); 
const ratios = Object.values(users);

const attempts = 1E6;
const counter = Array(userNames.length).fill(0);

const accPercentages = transformRatiosToAccPercentages(ratios);

for (let i = 1; i <= attempts; i++) {
  const index = chooseBiasedRandom(accPercentages);
  counter[index]++;
  // console.log(`Attempt ${i}: user ${userNames[index]} wins!`);
}

console.log(counter);
```

Comment: Hey, this works! do you have any idea how this could work if their sum isnt 1?

Comment: Their sum is not 1 in this example (ratios are 50, 100, 10). The sum of percentages, however, will be 1.

Comment: Oh okay! could you check trincot's answer and tell me if its as accurate as yours? i really cant understand how he managed to get such a short code

Comment: I suppose he explained his approach quite clealy in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    //put chances and user object in the same object, in an array
    let userChances = [
        {userObj: 'user1', chance: 20},
        {userObj: 'user2', chance: 40},
        {userObj: 'user2', chance: 60}
    ];
    //we loop the items and turn the chance into a running total...
    for (let i = 0; i < userChances.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            userChances[i] = {
                userObj: userChances[i].userObj,
                chance: userChances[i].chance + userChances[i - 1].chance
            };
        }
    }
    //now data looks like this:
    //let userChances = [
    //    {userObj: user1, chance: 20},
    //    {userObj: user2, chance: 60},
    //    {userObj: user2, chance: 120}
    //];
    //we get the total available chance, which is now the value of the chance property of the last element in the array
    let totalChances = userChances[userChances.length - 1].chance;
    let yourChance = Math.floor((Math.random() * totalChances) + 1);
    //loop one last time
    for (let i= 0; i < userChances.length; i ++) {
        //if our number is less than the current user chance, we found the user! return it! otherwise, proceed to check the next user...
        if (yourChance <= userChances[i].chance) {
            console.log('Winner', userChances[i].userObj);
            break;
        }
        //please note that if this does not return or break the loop, every user after this will be logged as a winner too!
    }
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the good answer, but it gives me the error that index is undefined?

Comment: Uh yeah sorry, I renamed `index` to `i` but I did not rename them all :) Fixed now

Comment: I renamed it, but the function returns undefined, does it work for you?

Comment: Ahah I'm the king of typos. There you go, there was `userObj` in some cases, `userObject` in others. Also, make sure you replace `user1`, `user2` and so on with your values.

Comment: I copied your code again, and unfortunately it still returns undefined

Comment: @AlejandroCastro ok now I really did debug it, also available in codepen.

Comment: @FabioLolli, do you know about the snippet function you can use in answers? Use the corresponding tool button in the editor. That way you can test your code inline, before posting.

Comment: @trincot thanks for the tip, I never realised it was so easy :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array with probabilities, and check and count against a random value.

This function first sets the return value to the last possible index, and then iterates over *until the rest of the random value is smaller than the actual probability*. Also, sum of all probabilities should be equal to one.

For implementation, you just need to take the function for getting an index for the array of users.

```
var users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
    probabilities = [0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
    selectedUser = users[getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities)];
```

Then, the code shows the distribution of indices.

```js
function getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities) {
    var r = Math.random(),
        index = probabilities.length - 1;

    probabilities.some(function (probability, i) {
        if (r < probability) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
        r -= probability;
    });
    return index;
}

var i,
    probabilities = [0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
    count = {},
    index;

probabilities.forEach(function (_, i) { count[i] = 0; });

for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    index = getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities);
    count[index]++;
}

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```