# Random algorithm with restricted outcome

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

Let's say you have a random algorithm which can choose between 2 elements however you want the 2nd element to have a chance of only 1% to be selected. What is the algorithmic logic behind it? 
Also any idea on how I could find more on this matter? I researched random algorithms with determined output but couldn't find answer to my question.

I looked into [Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) however I think that for now, it is not necessary to overcomplicate things.

Comment: uh well a simple way to do it, though probably not truly random and probably not usable for crypto would be .. use the languages random function to generate a number between 0 and 99... if 0 then pick the second element else pick the first

Comment: Related: [Generate a weighted random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435183/generate-a-weighted-random-number)

Answer (score 1):

```
int arr[2] = {1, 2};
return arr[(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) == 0)? 1 : 0];
```