# I am looking for a JavaScript random color generator to output the color red 10% of the time

Tags: javascript, colors

This is what I have so far, I have the background set to a solid color and a div that when clicked generates the random color. I want it to be generated by the space bar, and I want it to output red 10% of the time. I am an amateur at JavaScript but am learning.

```
var r, g, b, cstring;

function colapply() {
   color();

   r = newcolor.slice(1, 3);
   g = newcolor.slice(3, 5);
   b = newcolor.slice(5, 7);
   r = parseInt(r, 16);
   g = parseInt(g, 16);
   b = parseInt(b, 16);

   cstring = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
   $(".colorc").html("<" + "div class=" + "'" + "colorc1" + "'" + ">" + "<" + "/" + "div" + ">" + newcolor + "<span class='rgb'>" + cstring + "</span>");
   $("body").css({
      "background": newcolor
   });
   $(".colorc").css({
      "color": newcolor
   });

   $(".colorc1").css({
      "background": cstring
   });

}
var newcolor;

function color() {
   newcolor = '#' + (Math.random().toFixed(6).toString(16)).slice(2);;
   if (newcolor.length < 7) {
      color();
   }
}
$(".colorc").click(colapply);
colapply();
```

Comment: [Generate A Weighted Random Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435183/generate-a-weighted-random-number)

Answer (score 0):

Try introducing a special case for red.

```
function color() {
   if (Math.random() < 0.1) { // 10% of the time
      newcolor = '#FF0000'
      return;
    }
   newcolor = '#' + (Math.random().toFixed(6).toString(16)).slice(2);;
   if (newcolor.length < 7) {
      color();
   }
}
```

Comment: what if I only wanted either red or green to output, keeping red at 10% of the time?

Comment: Think about how you generate a random number between 0.0 and 1.0. Multiply the generated number (either in code or mentally) by 100, and you can think of it like 0-100 (%).
Then you have a range to divide this range according to you rules (10% for red means if your random generated number is less than 10, it should return red, else green)