# Create a Javasscript Random function with different probability

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

let there be a randomizer function with an argument array of characters

```
  CustomRandom(['b','c','a','z']){
}
```

the function returns a random character from the given input array

How can we write the code so that the probability of character returns is according to its index order in the array?
like the probability of returning characters should be  b<c<a<z

e.g  if we run the function 100 times the output can be

```
 b=>10,
  c=>20,
  a=>30,
  z=>40
```

they should not compulsorily return given value only.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8435183/519413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option would be to create a string like `bccaaazzzz`:

```
s = [...'bcaz'].map((c, i) => c.repeat(i + 1)).join('')
```

and then pick randomly from that string.